# How to set a default value for combo box

Tags: extjs

I have a combo box which has few static(hard coded) values which is displayed inside a grid.

By default it should show the first value in the combo box. I tried few things but it does not work.
I create the StaticComboBox first and then

```
      var StaticComboBox = Ext.extend(Ext.form.ComboBox, {
  mode: 'local',
  triggerAction: 'all',
  editable: false,
  valueField: 'value',
  displayField: 'label', 
  data: [], 
  initComponent: function() {
    this.store = new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
      fields: ['value', 'label'],
      data: this.data
    });
    StaticComboBox.superclass.initComponent.call(this);
  }
});


    var cm = new Ext.grid.ColumnModel([
    {
       id:'language',
       header: "Language",
       dataIndex: 'language',
       width: 235,
       menuDisabled: true,
       editor:  new StaticComboBox({
           name: 'Reasons',
           data: [
             [0, 'Reason 1'],
             [1, 'Second Reason'],
             [2, 'Something else']
           ]
         }),

         listeners: {
             load: function () {
                 //set the ComboBox value here
                 var combo = Ext.getCmp('language');
                 combo.setValue("1");
             }
          } 
    } 
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely you will get an **load** event cause your store already filled.
Try to listen render or something else.

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/4baem/3/

Use Ext.data.Store and then your data has to be an array of records:

```
new StaticComboBox({
       name: 'Reasons',
       data: [{value: 0, label: 'reason1'},  {value: 1, label: 'reason2'}]    
});
```